# How to store Mac documents in the iCloud?

Tags: icloud, iwork

So, iCloud is now available to all Mac and iOS5 users.

I don't (yet) have an iOS5 device, but i do have OS X Lion with iCloud installed. I've set it all up nice and (almost) easy. In iCloud PrefsPane I noticed there's an option to sync Documents & Data. This is what baffles me. How do I do that? How can I share Documents & Data between 2 Macs?

I understand that iOS5 iWork stores all documents in the iCloud, but what about Mac? How do I put files in the iCloud from Mac?

If I share a document via Share button in Pages/Numbers it goes to iWork.com, not the iCloud iWork.

Comment: This question is somewhat superseded by the new macOS Sierra feature for iCloud Drive Document and Desktop sync - see http://www.macworld.com/article/3098804/data-center-cloud/how-to-use-icloud-drive-s-new-desktop-and-documents-access-in-macos-sierra.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot treat iCloud as some sort of internet filesystem like Dropbox.  The only way to place data into the iCloud system is via an iCloud enabled app.  There is no generic way to access your iCloud files except via the application that put the files there in the first place.

So, in order to use iCloud, use iCloud enabled apps.  Use the same apps on 2 or more Macs, and that is how you share docs/data.

I'm not sure when the Mac iWork apps will get iCloud, I suspect in the next version which is now sorely overdue.

Comment: [This is not entirely true.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/what-is-the-workflow-between-iwork-apps-with-icloud/27494#27494) For now, you can use the [web interface](http://icloud.com/) to upload documents to iCloud.

Comment: the iOS iWork apps seem to be a special case.  Yes, you can access these documents via the iCloud login, but this is not a portal to iCloud documents in the cloud for all apps, only Pages/Numbers etc.

Comment: That's right. But it's worth mentioning, as the original question is mostly about iWork.

Comment: Very true.  Out of interest searching for iCloud in the Mac App Store yields 2 results for me, OS X Lion, and SingleText, which is a basic text editor that will sync contents from Macs to iOS devices using iCloud in the backend.  Safe to say that iCloud is off to a slow start on Mac so far...

Answer (score 0):

You can share Documents between Macs! I write an article about that! [Here it is](http://www.macbug.de/2011/12/29/icloud-beliebige-dokumente-zwischen-macs-synchronisieren/)!

> But this solution supports only Mac-to-Mac!

The iCloud-Concept is completely different, and it lets you only share Data through Apps.

But with this little trick, you can sync documents between Macs!

> For the iPhone, you can use [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) for storing documents in
>   the cloud!